# Form is submitted twice mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a ajax form when its submit button is clicked It is submitted twice means that control comes in controller action method twice, I am unable to find solution.

Comment: In addition to what @Ehsan suggested, you may check, if the button is of 'Submit' input type and some client side javascript/jquery event of the same submit button is not submitting your form again.

Comment: Yes I have checked that thanks @Siva Gopal

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suspect you have **jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js** included multiple times on page, in master layout and also in the child view which is causing the form to be posted multiple times.

in this case it is included two times, so form is posting two times. you have to make sure that it is included only once, include it `_Layout.cshtml` and remove from all child views.

These scripts are by default included in `_layout.cshtml` view so if you include them again in child view it will cause it to post form twice

Comment: ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
these three are included in my view @Ehsan Sajjad

Comment: in which view you have included in master layout or the view, post your master layout and the view in which you have Ajax Form

Comment: Thanks, I have removed ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and it is working fine I had all these scripts included in my view and I have removed the one mentioned now it is working fine @Ehsan Sajjad.

Comment: the scripts are by default included in `_layout.cshtml` view so if you include them again in child view it will cause it to post form twice

Comment: I had included the unobtrusive.js in a bundle, and the bundle was loaded twice on the _Layout with @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery").
The same solution of removing one duplicate reference worked.